# What's an appropriate ligand for Pd-Ag redox?

Tags: redox, coordination-compounds

I want to reduce palladium with silver ([in cellulose](https://unblinkingeye.com/Articles/Kallitype/kallitype.html)): $\ce{Pd^{2+} + 2Ag->2Ag+ +Pd}$. What is a good ligand and spectator ion for both metals? (The pH is not critical.) Ones I have considered:

- $\ce{[Pd(H2O)4](NO3)2}$: **Unstable**; hydrolyzes to insoluble hydroxides over time, except in strong acid, where the nitrate will oxidize the silver.
- $\ce{[PdCl4]^{2-}}$: Will **precipitate** $\ce{AgCl}$.
- $\ce{[Pd(NH3)4]^{2+}}$: $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]}$ can precipitate **explosive** $\ce{Ag3N}$.
- $\ce{[Pd(en)2}]^{2+}$, other common organic ligands: These are all seem to be very **poisonous**.
- Glycine-$\ce{(NO3)-}$: Maybe. I can't find any stability constant data.
- $\ce{(NH4)5[Pd(S2O3)4]}$: Definitely stable with silver, although I can't find a stability constant for palladium. EDIT: "This complex is not thermodynamically stable, and S-bridged oligomers are ultimately formed" according to [1], although maybe it could be stabilized somehow.
- $\ce{(NH4)+}$-$\ce{(SCN)-}$?

Are there any reasonable candidates that I haven't thought of? Any sources for stability constants, especially for thiosulfate?

[1] Thiosulfate Complexing of Platinum Group Elements.
Elizabeth Y. Anthony, Peter A. Williams. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bk-1994-0550.ch033